# Flash based File Uploader for ASP.NET

Tags: multifile-uploader

I searched for few hours. Most of the flash uploaders are php based.

I am having hard time finding flash(v10) based uploader for .NET, jQuery/JS

4 Main Requirements:

- Must support single file upload (for video file upload)
- Multi file upload for image upload
- Way to configure the upload location and file size, file type limitations etc
- Real time progress bar

**Is there anything around that I can adapt OR I can purchase for this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as per you asked but the basic idea regarding how to show progress bar and all try this article and make necessary changes as you needed

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/FileUploadWithProgrss.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This project is not flash based but still has progress bar.

Comment: I will look into this. Though it has single file support right now